# Tags go totally nuts on hover

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

There's a certain area around tags where they will flip constantly between their normal and hover states. Please see the following video for an illustration of the issue:

[image]

This is in Chrome stable in case it makes a difference.

Repro: Test [here](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/here)

Comment: Weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee...hours of fun.

Comment: hmm, doesn't behave like that in any of my browsers(Opera/Chrome/Mozilla/IE)

Comment: Yeah, this bugs me. tags in chat do it too. I think it varies a bit by site though. Depends if the border width changes. It doesn't work on MSO for instance

Comment: just imagine if they had hover sound o_O

Comment: Can anyone repro *right now*?

Comment: @Sklivvz: I can't

Comment: @Sklivvz I can, the CSS doesn't appear to have changed since I described the problem in my answer.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Oh, right. This only applied to tags *in* posts, not below them. At least that's how it is for me right now. So, yeah, as Tim says, problem is still there.

Comment: Weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee...hours of fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in `rev. 1340`.

Comment: Crazy flipping mouse cursor, you will be missed.

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, on Super User `.post-text a:hover`'s `border-bottom: 1px #6C0000 dotted;` is more specific than the border defined for `.post-text .post-tag`, and the variation in border definitions causes it to flip back and forth between the hover and non-hover states.

Tweaking the selector/adding the border definition to the `.post-text a.post-tag:hover` style should fix things.